# What is the running time of this program? (if we have a for loop which is inside a while loop)

Tags: python, performance

```
def hsum(X):
    while len(X) > 1:
        Y=[None]*(len(X)//2)
        for i in range(0,len(X)//2):
            Y[i] =  X[2*i] + X[(2*i)+1]
        X=Y
    return X[0]
```

Here X is an array of integers and the length of X is n=2^k. And the length decreases (as in n//2) after it enters the while loop and that decreased length is the range of the for loop ( for example, n=2^6 = 64 and as it enters the while loop it decreases to n//2, so the range of the for loop is 
(0, 64/2 = 32). So, the running time of while loop is O(log n), but what would be the running time of the for loop? And what is the running time of the whole code in terms of Big-Oh?

Comment: Welcome. This is Python code, so you'll probably get more answers if you change the tag to Python instead of Java.

Comment: I also think there is a mistake in the code you are asking about; the `while n > 1:` condition cannot change from true to false in order for the loop to terminate, since the loop body contains no assignment to `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a straightforward way to determine the big-O complexity of this algorithm. The `+` operation on line 5 is executed at least as many times as anything else in the code, so if we can count how many times `+` is done, then that will be the same as the complexity of the whole algorithm. This is sound because everything else is a basic operation, except the line `Y = [None] * len(X // 2)`, which does not have a higher complexity than the loop with the `+` in.

Since the algorithm computes the sum of the numbers in the list, and does not add anything *except* numbers from the list (or partial sums of numbers from the list), there are a total of `len(X) - 1` additions done, and therefore the algorithm is O(*n*) where *n* is the length of the input list.

Thinking of it another way, you can visualise this algorithm as adding the leaf nodes from a binary tree. The number of additions is equal to the number of internal nodes in a binary tree with *n* leaves, which is *n* - 1, or O(*n*).

Comment: Thanks a lot..But i have another confusion.. The Big-oh of the while loop is O(log n), right? So, should the running time of the whole code be O(n logn), as in n for addition and log n for the while loop?

Comment: The outer loop indeed runs O(log *n*) times, and the inner loop runs O(`len(X)`) times, but there is a trap here. `len(X)` itself is not O(*n*) since *n* refers to the length of the **input**, but `len(X)` changes while the algorithm runs; so you can't just multiply these together. The inner loop runs *n* / 2 = 2^(k-1) times, then 2^(k-2) times, then 2^(k-3), and so on, until the last iteration of the outer loop when it runs for only one iteration. The total of these is a geometric progression 2^(k-1) + 2^(k-2) + ... + 1 = 2^k - 1 = *n* - 1, as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much...I understood the concept